# Negative variance of linear combination of regression coefficients

Tags: variance, contrasts, arithmetic

I'm going crazy over this so I hope someone can help me.. First a presentation of my case:

I have a complex multiple regression model with 4 predictors (some terms that don't concern this issue are left out here):

$Z=b_0+b_1X+b_2Y+b_5X^2+b_7XY+b_9XV+b_{10}XW+b_{11}YV+e$

I am trying to test whether the slope along the $Y=-X$ is significant while $V$ and $W$ are kept constant. At my disposal, I have the regression coefficients, their SEs, and covariances.

I have rewritten the above equation at $Y=-X$, inserting $-X$ for $Y$:

$Z=b_0+(b_1-b_2+b_9V+b_{10}W-b_{11}V)X+(b_5-b_7)X^2+e$

Thus, the linear combination of coefficients for the slope along $Y=-X$ should be:
$(b_1-b_2+b_9V+b_{10}W-b_{11}V)$

and it's variance:
$SE_{b1}^2+SE_{b2}^2+V^2SE_{b9}^2+W^2SE_{b10}^2+V^2SE_{b11}^2-2covb_1b_2+2Vcovb_1b_9+2Wcovb_1b_{10}-2Vcovb_1b_{11}-2Vcovb_2b_{9}-2Wcovb_2b_{10}+2Vcovb_2b_{11}+2VWcovb_9b_{10}-2V^2covb_9b_{11}-2VWcovb_{10}b_{11}$

However, somehow I end up with a negative variance when inserting values. I realize I must have made some simple error, but I can't find it. Part of the problem may be that I'm not completely sure I know what I'm doing...

So, please, what have I done wrong?

Edit: I have tried to adapt the simpler equations found here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10869-010-9183-4 (note that one equation is corrected in the erratum here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10869-013-9317-6), and found useful information on this site: http://public.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/faculty/edwardsj/moderatedpolynomialregression.htm

### MAJOR EDIT:

I beg forgiveness. In the end, it turned out to be a miss-specified cell reference that led to the problem by referring to the wrong covariance. The formula seem to be correct.

Comment: $SE_{b1}^2+SE_{b2}^2+V^2SE_{b9}^2+W^2SE_{b10}^2+P^2SE_{b11}^2-2covb_1b_2+2Vcovb_1b_9+2Wcovb_1b_{10}-2Pcovb_1b_{11}-2Vcovb_2b_{9}-2Wcovb_2b_{10}+2Pcovb_2b_{11}+2VWcovb_9b_{10}-2VPcovb_9b_{11}-2PWcovb_{10}b_{11}$. You showed the same formula one would get by replacing $P$ with $V$

Comment: I am sorry, the P should have been a V, so that is not the problem. That was a typo here, not in the original calculation.

Comment: It seems to me you are confusing parameters and variables. I think the variances and covariances should be related to variables ($X$, $Y$, $V$, $W$) not to parameters ($b_i$). For example the variance of $b_1+b_{10}W$ is $b_{10}^2 Var(W)$, and the variance of $b_1-b_2$ is $0$.

Comment: @Federico Tedeschi Possibly, but it is the significance of the combination of parameters that are of interest and it is therefore the variances and covariances of the parameters that I use. I base my formulas on http://public.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/faculty/edwardsj/moderatedpolynomialregression.htm, where variances and covariances are used as I do.

Comment: Ok, I understand: you consider variables as fixed and coefficients as not. I think you made a mistake. In fact, it's: $Z=b_0+(b_1-b_2+b_9V+b_{10}W-b_{11}V)X+(b_5-b_7)X^2+e$, i.e. the sign before $b_7$ is wrong.

Comment: That is true, thank you for pointing it out. Unfortunately, that is another typo in this post (I was in a hurry which, apparently, led to more than one mistake) and not in my original calculations. Besides, $b_5-b_7$ is not part of the expression for the variance of the slope, only the curvature. The typo is corrected now.

Comment: I don't know if your procedure is correct because I don't understand the issue. However, even if calculating the variance of the quantity $(b_1-b_2+b_9V+b_{10}W-b_{11}V)$ were completely pointless, such quantity couldn't be negative anyway, because it's a variance. Since I cannot find further mistakes on your formulas, I guess the mistake occurred at a later stage.